# Why is my C# string not affecting my stored procedures IF statements?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm using T-SQL and this is one of my stored procedures as you can read, depending on what my parameter (`@para_type`) is either `Employee` or `Consultant`, the following statements will execute and triggers will be upon fired. The stored procedure is working when it's executed in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).

Where I enter the following:

```
 execute update_person @para_salary = 800, @para_ssn = 17,
                       @para_companyName = 'Ikea',@para_expdate = '20201230',
                       @para_type = 'Consultant', @para_officeId = 2
```

But then in my C# Winforms code, I use a textbox to fill the  parameter for T-SQL (`@para_type`). It is not affecting my stored procedure's `IF` statements. I've debugged it in C# and everything is executed accordingly but my stored procedure won't do what is programmed for.

Stored procedure:

```
create procedure update_person
    @para_salary varchar(25),
    @para_ssn int,
    @para_companyName varchar(25),
    @para_expdate date,
    @para_type varchar(10),
    @para_officeId int
as 
begin
    if @para_ssn is null
        print('Please enter a value for (ssn)')
   else if @para_type = 'Employee'
        delete from consultant 
        where ssn = @para_ssn        

   update person 
   set flag = @para_type
   where ssn = @para_ssn

   update employee
   set salary = @para_salary
   where ssn = @para_ssn     

   if @para_type = 'Consultant'
        delete from employee 
        where ssn = @para_ssn           

   update person 
   set flag = @para_type
   where ssn = @para_ssn

   update consultant
   set companyName = @para_companyName, expdate = @para_expdate
   where ssn = @para_ssn 

   update works_at
   set officeId = @para_officeId
   where ssn = @para_ssn
end
```

C# Winform the view:

```
public void initializeComboBoxes()
{ 
     var arr1 = new string[] { "Employee", "Consultant" };

     foreach (var item in arr1)
         add_person_combobox.Items.Add(item);

     add_person_combobox.SelectedIndex = 0;

     foreach (var item in arr1)
         update_person_combobox.Items.Add(item);

     update_person_combobox.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

private void lblTimer(int i)
{
    var t = new Timer();

    t.Interval = i;

    t.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            ResponseLbl.Text = "";
            t.Stop();
        };

    t.Start();
}

private void update_person_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(update_person_salary.Text))
    {
        update_person_salary.Text = "0";
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(update_person_CoName.Text))
    {
        update_person_CoName.Text = "Lund Consulting AB";
    }

    int ssn = Convert.ToInt32(update_person_ssn.Text);            
    string type = update_person_combobox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    int salary = Convert.ToInt32(update_person_salary.Text);
    string comName = update_person_CoName.Text;

    int officeId = update_person_officeId.SelectedIndex + 1;
    DateTime expdate = update_person_expDate.Value.Date;

    if (ctrl.update_person(salary, ssn, comName, expdate, type, officeId) == true)              
    {                     
        ResponseLbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        ResponseLbl.Text = "Succesfull";
        lblTimer(3000);               
    }
    else
    {
        ResponseLbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        ResponseLbl.Text = "Failed";
        lblTimer(3000);
    }
}
```

C# data access layer

```
public bool update_person(int ssn, int salary, string companyName, DateTime expdate, string type, int officeId)
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();

        cmd = new SqlCommand("update_person", con);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;            

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@para_ssn", ssn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@para_salary", salary);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@para_companyName", companyName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@para_expdate", expdate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@para_type", type);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@para_officeId", officeId);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        return true;
    }
    catch (SqlException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("error: " + e.Message);
        con.Close();
        return false;
    }                      
}
```

Comment: I guess **CR** symbol or **space\tab** at the end of parameter. Change `if @para_type = 'Consultant'` to `if @para_type LIKE 'Consultant%'`. The same for `else if @para_type = 'Employee'` => `else if @para_type LIKE 'Employee%'`. Or don't allow user to type parameter type, better use radio button.

Comment: @para_salary is expected to be a varchar but you pass an integer. Fix this problem before.

Comment: @lad2025 Just tried it out, but it wont work. Im going to try debugg in SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: The first parameter of _update_person_ is _ssn_  and the second is _salary_ but you call this method with _ctrl.update_person(salary, ssn,...._ swapping these two values. So your query works using wrong data.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing BEGIN and END in blocks of your procedure..

```
BEGIN
 if @para_ssn is null
    print('Please enter a value for (ssn)')
else if @para_type = 'Employee'
    BEGIN
      delete from consultant where ssn = @para_ssn        

      update person set flag = @para_type where ssn = @para_ssn
      update employee set salary = @para_salary where ssn = @para_ssn     
     END
else if @para_type = 'Consultant'
    BEGIN
      delete from employee where ssn = @para_ssn           
      update person set flag = @para_type where ssn = @para_ssn
      update consultant set companyName = @para_companyName, expdate = @para_expdate where ssn = @para_ssn 
      update works_at set officeId = @para_officeId where ssn = @para_ssn
    END
END
```